# Spring Boot Application doesn't run from war in command line

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat7, embedded-jetty, google-sheets-api, embedded-tomcat-7

I am trying use google sheet API. I was able to connect to my google sheet as a standalone code base. I was trying to run the same with spring boot application. I created a war file along with spring boot integrated. When I run

java -jar myApp.war

It fails with the below error,

```js
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: **Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.setJarScanFilter(Lorg/apache/tomcat/JarScanFilter;)V**
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:137) ~[spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.9.RELEASE]
        at com.nielsen.google.myna.App.main(App.java:17) [classes!/:1]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [myna-1.war:1]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [myna-1.war:1]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) [myna-1.war:1]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.WarLauncher.main(WarLauncher.java:59) [myna-1.war:1]
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.setJarScanFilter(Lorg/apache/tomcat/JarScanFilter;)V
```

I have the below pom.xml,

```html
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <groupId>com.api.google</groupId>
 <artifactId>myApp</artifactId>
 <version>1</version>
 <packaging>war</packaging>

 <name>myApp</name>
 <description>api test</description>

 <properties>
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
 </properties>

 <parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
 </parent>

 <dependencies>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
   <artifactId>google-api-services-calendar</artifactId>
   <version>v3-rev281-1.23.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
   <artifactId>google-api-services-sheets</artifactId>
   <version>v4-rev498-1.23.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
   <artifactId>google-oauth-client</artifactId>
   <version>1.23.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
   <artifactId>google-oauth-client-java6</artifactId>
   <version>1.23.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
   <artifactId>google-oauth-client-jetty</artifactId>
   <version>1.23.0</version>
   <!-- <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
     <artifactId>org.mortbay.jetty</artifactId>
     <groupId>jetty</groupId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
     <artifactId>org.mortbay.jetty</artifactId>
     <groupId>servlet-api</groupId>
    </exclusion>
   </exclusions> -->
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.json</groupId>
   <artifactId>json</artifactId>
   <version>20171018</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>junit</groupId>
   <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
   <version>3.8.1</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
 </dependencies>
 <build>
  <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   </plugin>
  </plugins>
 </build>

</project>
```

It looks like some conflict between embedded tomcat server but i couldn't resolve this.

Comment: https://github.com/paulc4/microservices-demo/issues/12. to run it as java application, you should package it as "jar", not "war". war file is used to deploy to tomcat server or other web server, not for java application.

Comment: yes it worked. @Surely Thank you! for your quick response. Let me try to deploy the war in tomcat and test.